# Heading in the center

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, material-ui, jsx

I am new to reactjs and am facing some issues in the ui. I am trying to center my header in the space between my app bar and my navlink. However the heading is not coming in the center.

[image]

What is happening is that the navbar is taking up space at the top how do I modify it such that the heading is in the center.

Here is the code:

```
return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className={useStyles.root}>
            <AppBar position="static">
              <NavLink to="dashboard">
                <ListItem button>
                  <ListItemIcon>
                    <DashboardIcon />
                  </ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText
                    style={{ color: "#FFFFFF" }}
                    
                  />
                </ListItem>
              </NavLink>

              <Typography
                gutterBottom
                align="center"
                style={{ width: "100%", alignItems: "center" }}
              >
                Best Practices Management System
              </Typography>
            </AppBar>
          </div>
          <br />
          <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} style={{ marginLeft: "5%" }}>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <TextField
                  label="Title"
                  variant="outlined"
                  size="small"
                  name="Title"
                  id="Title"
                  placeholder="Enter the Title of the Best Practice"
                  onChange={handleChange("Title")}
                  defaultValue={values.Title}
                  multiline
                  rows={2}
                  rowsMax={4}
                  style={{ width: "90%" }}
                />
                <label
                  id="title"
                  style={{ visibility: "hidden", color: "red" }}
                >
                  Title must be atleast 5 characters long
                </label>
              </Grid>

              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <TextField
                  placeholder="Enter the details of the Best Practice"
                  label="Details of Best Practice"
                  id="Details"
                  size="small"
                  name="Details"
                  onChange={handleChange("Details")}
                  defaultValue={values.Details}
                  style={{ width: "90%" }}
                  variant="outlined"
                  multiline
                  rows={2}
                  rowsMax={4}
                />
                <label
                  id="details"
                  style={{ visibility: "hidden", color: "red" }}
                >
                  Details of Best Practice must be atleast 10 characters long
                </label>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <TextField
                  placeholder="What is the Best Practice?"
                  label="What is the Best Practice"
                  size="small"
                  id="What"
                  name="What"
                  onChange={handleChange("What")}
                  defaultValue={values.What}
                  style={{ width: "90%" }}
                  variant="outlined"
                  multiline
                  rows={2}
                  rowsMax={4}
                />
                <label id="what" style={{ visibility: "hidden", color: "red" }}>
                  What is the Best Practice must be atleast 10 characters long
                </label>
              </Grid>

              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <TextField
                  placeholder="Why was the Best Practice Implemented"
                  label="Why was the Best Practice Implemented"
                  size="small"
                  name="Why"
                  id="Why"
                  onChange={handleChange("Why")}
                  defaultValue={values.Why}
                  style={{ width: "90%" }}
                  variant="outlined"
                  multiline
                  rows={2}
                  rowsMax={4}
                />
                <label id="why" style={{ visibility: "hidden", color: "red" }}>
                  Why was the Best Practice implemented must be atleast 10
                  characters long
                </label>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <TextField
                  placeholder="How was the Best Practice Implemented"
                  label="How was the Best Practice Implemented"
                  size="small"
                  name="How"
                  id="How"
                  onChange={handleChange("How")}
                  defaultValue={values.How}
                  style={{ width: "90%" }}
                  variant="outlined"
                  multiline
                  rows={2}
                  rowsMax={4}
                />
                <label id="how" style={{ visibility: "hidden", color: "red" }}>
                  How was the Best Practice implemented must be atleast 10
                  characters long
                </label>
              </Grid>

              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <FormControl id="Status" style={{ width: "90%" }} size="small">
                  <InputLabel
                    htmlFor="Implementation_Status"
                    id="Status"
                    style={{
                      marginLeft: 10,
                      top: "50%",
                      transform: "translate(0,-50%"
                    }}
                  >
                    Implementation Status
                  </InputLabel>
                  <Select
                    labelId="Implementation_Status"
                    name="Status"
                    id="Status"
                    onChange={handleChange("Status")}
                    defaultValue={values.Status}
                    variant="outlined"
                    inputProps={{
                      id: "Implementation_Status",
                      name: "age"
                    }}
                  >
                    <MenuItem value="1">Implemented</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="2">Implementation in Progress</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="3">Not Implemented</MenuItem>
                  </Select>
                </FormControl>
                <label
                  id="status"
                  style={{ visibility: "hidden", color: "red" }}
                >
                  Implementation Status cannot be blank
                </label>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <Form.Group controlId="TBD_COST">
                  <TextField
                    placeholder="Cost of Implementation of the Best Practice"
                    label="Cost of Implementation"
                    name="Cost"
                    id="Cost"
                    size="small"
                    onChange={handleChange("Cost")}
                    defaultValue={values.Cost}
                    style={{ width: "90%" }}
                    variant="outlined"
                  />
                  <label
                    id="cost"
                    style={{ visibility: "hidden", color: "red" }}
                  >
                    Cost of Implementation cannot be left blank
                  </label>
                </Form.Group>
              </Grid>

              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <TextField
                  placeholder="Benefits of the Best Practice"
                  label="Benefits of the Best Practice"
                  size="small"
                  name="Benefits"
                  id="Benefits"
                  onChange={handleChange("Benefits")}
                  defaultValue={values.Benefits}
                  style={{ width: "90%" }}
                  variant="outlined"
                  multiline
                  rows={2}
                  rowsMax={4}
                />
                <label
                  id="benefits"
                  style={{ visibility: "hidden", color: "red" }}
                >
                  Benefits must be at least 10 characters long
                </label>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Grid
              container
              direction="row"
              justify="left"
              alignItems="left"
              style={{ width: "83%" }}
            >
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                size="small"
                color="primary"
                style={styles.button}
                onClick={this.continue}
              >
                Continue
              </Button>
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                size="small"
                color="primary"
                type="submit"
                style={styles.button}
              >
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Form>
        </React.Fragment>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

I am using material Ui for my code. Please help

The code for Use styles

const useStyles = makeStyles({
root: {
width: "100%",

```
maxWidth: 500
```

}
});

Comment: can you post the code for DashboardIcon and useStyles?

Comment: I have posted the code for use styles in the question. I imported dashboard icon from material ui icons

Comment: @sandeep pradhan Please provide complete code or in the sandbox so that we can check your issue.

Comment: could you provide the link for the sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/edit-mode-autocomplete-formik-material-ui-react-forked-exyp2?file=/src/index.js:247-550)

You need to wrap the AppBar components with Toolbar and remove the `gutterBottom`, something like:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <AppBar position="static">
    <Toolbar>
      <NavLink to="dashboard">
        <DashboardIcon />
      </NavLink>
      <Typography
        align="center"
        style={{ width: "100%", alignItems: "center" }}
      >
        Best Practices Management System
      </Typography>
    </Toolbar>
  </AppBar>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: The dashboard Icon is also a link to go to another page, so require the navbar

Comment: so wrap the DashboardIcon with a NavLink. answer updated.